Weak convergence using infinitely differentiable test functions
The definition of weak convergence is often stated as
$$
P_n \to_w P ~~\text{if and only if}~~ \int f dP_n \to \int f dP
$$
for all $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded function. Is it true that as long as the above holds for all test functions that are infinitely differentiable with bounded derivatives? Under what specific conditions on $S$ would this hold?

No. $x\mapsto x$. If $S$ is compact, then yes.
